# Printing from Highcharts returns focus to the top of the page

Tags: printing, highcharts

I have a page with multiple charts.  When I scroll down to print a chart, the page returns focus to the top of the page, not the chart I just printed.  Haven't found anything on the boards related to this, so hoping someone has encountered this and has a suggestion.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ND5xf/

Scroll down to the third chart and choose to print. You can either print it or cancel the window.  The page will return focus to the first chart.

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="container3" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Line Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5]
        }, {
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7]
        }]
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#container2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Bar Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [107, 31, 635]
        }, {
            data: [133, 156, 947]
        }]
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#container3').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Column Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4]

        }, {
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts prints a single chart by hiding everything else on the page and then printing.  It looks like that in this *shuffle* of DOM elements a potential scroll bar is forgotten.  The only fix I can see (without modifying the source) is to take control of the printing yourself and reset the scroll position.

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: [{
                 text: 'Print Chart',
                 onclick: function() {
                     var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
                     this.print();
                     setTimeout(function(){
                          $(document).scrollTop(scrollPos)
                     }, 1001); // Highcharts has a 1s delay before display elements again
                 }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ND5xf/1/) (try the 3rd chart).

Comment: Thanks man. Works! I did not need to actually set the timeout. Worked without it too is super smooth.